# Spring JDBC connection issue-Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

I am stuck into a big trouble that i cannot connect the oracle 11g database form my Spring MVC application.
The error i am getting is

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
```

also,
in the stack trace i'm getting the error-

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

If you can help me to resolve the issue, it will be a great help. 
I am providing my configuration and coding details below:

> Default-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${jdbc.maxPoolSize}" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${jdbc.minPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="${jdbc.maxStatements}" />
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="${jdbc.testConnection}" />
</bean>

<bean id="userAuthenticationRepository" 
            class="com.era.repository.impl.UserAuthenticationRepositoryImpl">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

> UserAuthenticationRepositoryImpl.java

```
@Repository
```

public class UserAuthenticationRepositoryImpl implements UserAuthenticationRepository {

```
@Qualifier("dbDataSource")
private DataSource dataSource;

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}


public User getUserAuthentication(User userToBeAuthenticated) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String query = "select id, name, role from User where login =";
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder();
    queryString.append(" SELECT ")
                           .append( "*" )
                           .append(" FROM table_name ")
                           .append(" WHERE login = ? ");
                Object[] parameterList = { userToBeAuthenticated.getLogin() };
                SqlRowSet dataRow = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(queryString.toString(), parameterList);

                if (dataRow.next()) {
                    System.out.println("Query executed successfully");
                }
    return null;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using maven, note here you can't directly get Oracle driver jar to `.m2` due to *licence* restriction, so you may need to manually download and place it to your repository.You may find this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-your-maven-local-repository/) helpful.

Comment: that link really helped. Thank you so much.